# What to do if more than 2 hamburger icons in nav bar?

Tags: responsive-design

I am building a website for each office within an agency (about 6-8 different offices). I want to make it easy for a visitor to jump to another office website when on an office website. So, each office website will have a dropdown list in a navbar that can be used to jump to a specific office page.

**Problem:** The ABC Network dropdown is competing against the main nav dropdown for the "P" office when the viewport changes to tablet/mobile view (examples below).

Question:

1. **How would you differentiate between the 2 navs? Should we consolidate all into one main toggle nav?**

***DESKTOP VIEW***

[image: Desktop view]

***MOBILE VIEW***
[image]

Comment: Hamburger icons? Surely they could've come up with a better name for that! It doesnt even make any sense in the context it's used in. "Open the menu" "wheres the menu?!" "click the hamburger icon up the top right" "I dont see any effing hamburgers!" "sigh…"

Answer (score 2):

Two hamburgers would thoroughly confuse users. Combining the two menus is not a viable solution as the two menus are at a different level of hierarchy.

One solution could be to replace the top hamburger menu with something more obvious, for example:

[image: Top menu navigation]

Comment: I assume this would need to be done in both desktop and mobile view, otherwise it would be inconsistent and confusing.